# Events in Panel data set

Tags: regression, panel-data, model

I would like to estimate the impact that a certain event has on my dependent variable. I hope you can help me.

More precisely, I have a panel data set of the yearly number of IPOs for each EU member from 1989-2018, i.e. 28 countries, 30 years.

What I want to find out is, if the adoption of the common currency, the adoption of the common market, and eu membership has a positive impact on the number of IPOs. I.e.: Are there more IPOs after event X,Y,Z than before?

The problem I see, is that all these events happend at different times for different countries, and sometimes not at all.

How could I test for the impact of these events? Is there a way?

I am thankful for any feedback.

Thank You,

Fabian.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is the `difference-in-difference (DiD)` approach for panel data when you have a `policy` that was introduced and you want to measure its impact: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_in_differences. Let me know that's what you are looking for and I can add this as an answer with more explanation.

Comment: One of the assumptions of difference-in-difference is that nothing else except the treatment changes in both groups which is almost certainly not the case here. But any economics textbook on panel data will offer some useful techniques (see e.g. Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data by Wooldridge).

Comment: @VitaliAvagyan  you so much for your answer.

1. The DiD approach looks interesting. I have some questions, however. Does this work for the events happening at different times for the different countries? As is the case for e.g. adopting the Euro. Or would I need several DiD and compare results? Also, as a 'control group' is needed for DiD, to what degree would this group need to be comparable to the 'treatment group'? Thanks

Comment: @mloning Thank you for the reconmendation.

 I took a look at the book by Wooldridge, and it seems like a Poisson Regression might work. Looking through other sources, an intervention model might also be an option. Howver, my concerns are similar as for the DiD. Do these work for events happening in differen years? Thanks

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind is to create indicator variables for EU, Euro and common market membership. Together with country fixed effects you could try to estimate their coefficients and see if they are statistically significant.

Comment: @mloning thank you for your new input.
I have decided, however, to try a mixed linear model. I will see how this one goes, and return to one of your ideas if necessary.